# Polarized Coherent Beam Hits a Polarizer Off-Polarization Angle While Varying Distance?

Tags: experimental-physics, polarization, coherence

Just wondering about an experiment that should be easy to perform on an optical bench:

A coherent beam is polarized.  It then hits another polarizer which is set to permit a polarization angle off that of the incident beam.  The distance of this second polarizer is varied in steps much smaller than the wavelength of the light.  The intensity of the re-polarized beam exiting the backside of the second polarizer, vs distance is plotted.

Is it constant?

Is there a cite of such an experiment so I can read it?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a position dependence? By which mechanism would the second polarizer know where it is relative to the first one?

Comment: I don't necessarily expect there to be a position dependence.  This is just an experiment that is somewhat cheaper than say aLIGO or the LHC, hence might not demand as much in the way of theoretic justification.  However, having said that, it would be interesting to know what the Standard Model says should happen and then test this prediction the way, for example, everyone knows GR is true but large amounts of money are spent testing it nevertheless.

Comment: The second polarizer would know where it was relative to the first by the wave number between the two.

Comment: The standard model? That's about high energy behavior of quantum fields. You don't have any of that here, this is a simple optical experiment and the only relevant question is "How does the polarizer know where it is relative to the other one?". How would the polarize measure the number of waves? I don't see any interference between two beams in here.

Comment: I don't see why saying "the standard model" implies only high energy.

'...the Standard Model is sometimes regarded as the "theory of almost everything".'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Comment: I should have said "the fractional changes in wave number between the initial and final positions of the second polarizer"

Comment: One shouldn't believe everything that is being posted on Wikipedia. For one thing, the standard model is a model, not a theory, for another, it's basically useless for low energy problems and there is absolutely no reason to use it in this case. You still need to answer the question where the polarizer gets its location information from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38315/discussion-between-james-bowery-and-curiousone).